# Program crashes on STRB instruction on ARMv6

Tags: string, assembly, arm

While learning ARMv6 ASM (using raspberry pi) I was trying to implement a loop which would modify the contents of a string, however I cannot seem to store the modified byte back to memory.
Using GDB and breaking at various points shows me all registry values are working perfectly until it comes to the STRB instruction. Then it crashes for some unknown reason.
The loop should decrement all bytes by 1 in reverse order.

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* Thumb mode */
    .code 32
    add     r6, pc, #1
    bx      r6

    .code 16
    mov     r4, #6
    mov     r0, pc
    add     r0, #16

loop:
    /*load, modify, store*/
    ldrb    r3, [r0]
    sub     r3, #1
    strb    r3, [r0] /*THIS IS BROKEN*/

    sub     r0, #1
    sub     r4, r4, #1
    bne     loop

    bx lr

.data
string:
    asciz "HiThere"
```

The STRB instruction seems to crash the program, I am using an old book to learn from, am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT: yes I know that isnt the best way to load r0 but it works...i guess it could use a label in future.
EDIT2: Sorry I know my question was badly written, Ive included more code for clarity. Still crashes on STRB when stepping through in gdb.

Comment: you starting at the back end of the string and going backward?

Comment: what makes you think the strb is the problem?

Comment: is there code you are not showing there, for example after the bne where is the code that ends the program/function?  If that is all the code then you are crashing on executing "HiThere" as code.

Comment: are you bare metal or are you running this code in linux somehow?  if you can ldrb an address you can strb it so long as there isnt some protection mechanism in place (doesnt mean it will WORK, for example if this was in rom which it isnt on a raspberry pi but in general) for example if this is all considered .text and part of some linux binary where the .text might be considered read only and asserted that way in the mmu.

Comment: That looks like Thumb code to me. That would make each instruction 2 bytes in size, so how did you arrive at `28` as an offset when you calculate the string address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: rather than increasing r0, your loop decreases it. So, rather than scrolling through the string, you are scrolling up straight into your code, overwriting instructions with less-by-one byte values. Once you overwrite the strb instruction, SIGILL happens.

Replace

```
sub     r0, #1
```

with

```
add     r0, #1
```

---

PREVIOUS: I see r0 being initialized to a memory location in the code section, past pc. Is that a writable memory block? I'm not so sure.

Place the string in the data section instead.

---

EDIT: there's another thing; your loop has no exit condition. SUB doesn't set flags unless told to; so replace

```
sub     r4, r4, #1
```

with

```
subs     r4, r4, #1
```

Comment: I had the same problem with in the string in the data section so I moved into text. Neither seems to work I cant see why :(

Comment: What's the execution environment? Linux? Is debugging an option?

Comment: Linux environment, debugging with GDB.

Comment: So what are the signal details?

Comment: Im kinda new to this stuff but gdb crashes with SIGILL - illegal instruction signal. Im thinking the memory block isnt writable?

Comment: ahh yes! I think you're right. Ill modify the code when I get back and see what happens, look like I was accidently overwriting the frame pointer! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: "Frame pointer" is something completely different. It's code you've been overwriting.

Comment: Thanks Seva,I looked into it and it turns out that when in Thumb mode the code automatically compiles to subs rather than just sub instruction. I guess it doesn't hurt to be explicit though.